# Cell/Row spacing in TableView

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a table in `JavaFX` which looks like this.

[image]

As there is some space between each row. I want to remove those spaces.

How can I do that?

Here is my `CSS` code -

```
.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-font-family:Bookman Old Style;
    -fx-font-size:12.0;
    -fx-border-color:#FFFFFF;
    -fx-padding:0.0px;
}
```

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: I have already shared the `CSS` code of my table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to remove the spaces between rows. It can be done like this.

```
.table-row-cell{
    -fx-cell-size:15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we dont have any code/demo to look at below things could be useful for you

to remove extra space you need to use `border-collapse: collapse;`

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

or if you want you can add `cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0` to `table` tag

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
```

Comment: `border-collapse` is not supported in `javafx`

Comment: You're obviously refering to HTML here. This approach won't be of much use for someone working with JavaFX.